# Someone is copying my blog content. Does it affect my blog’s ranking on Google?

Tags: google, duplicate-content, copyright

I have posted one blog post about SEO interview questions last month, but I found that someone copied the content of my post and updated in their wordpress blog yesterday with no change. He/she didn’t give link back to my post or anything referring my post. I don’t like this kind of activity. I asked them to give link back to me but no response. My post was cache by Google already and that stolen post hasn’t cache by Google. If it cache by Google will it affect my Post? How avoid those content copies? Does it possible to complaint Google above it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Excerpts](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2011/08/summaries-of-google-webmaster-central.html) from the answer by Matt Cutts of Google for the question - [How can I make sure that Google knows my content is original?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4LsB19wTt0Q)

*Google tries hard but is not perfect at identifying who is the original author of an article. To let Google index your original article faster before a deceptive site like a scraper, claims it is its own (by showing a manipulated timestamp), let the world know about it by, for example, tweeting about it or hook up thinks like [Pub Subhubhub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) which will ping various places to asynchronously say that there's a new article or blog post.
Alternatively, you can do a [DMCA (Digital Millenium Copyright Act) notice](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-notice?pli=1&) or a spam report*